# Saving configuration with Vagrant packages

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm getting started with Vagrant and spent some time installing packages, setting up my DB and adding some data to the DB.  Now that I have a base working box for my development environment, I would like to share this image with colleagues, that they can use as local VMs.

Is this not possible with vagrant?  I just tried `vagrant package` and then destroyed it and did a `vagrant up` with my `config.vm.box_url` pointed to that packaged box location.  To my dismay none of my installed packages, or files and configurations were included with my packaged vm.

Am I misunderstanding what vagrant is for or perhaps expecting vagrant to do something it's not designed to do here?  If installed packages aren't the purpose of `vagrant package`, then what use cases is it for?

I've read through the docs and not found answers to these questions there.

Of course I can provision everything, and I'll get there too, but it's not what I'm getting at in this question.

Answer (score 1):

I've since come to the conclusion that vagrant is basically for provisioning.  If I need this I can just use virtual-box, but provisioning is a better approach because system packages and application dependencies etc. are a moving target.

Using provisioning allows future provisions to stay up to date and potentially expose incompatibilities.

Comment: I'm glad you've found out about the benefits of provisioning. I would recommend a very useful provisioning project called [Vaprobash](https://github.com/fideloper/Vaprobash). I personally use it to set up my development environment and it is extremely useful. 

Just generate a Vagrant file with it and share with your colleagues.

Comment: Thanks.  We actually use salt to provision our vagrant (+ staging, production) boxes, it's been working wonderfully!